# How do I prevent an error message from repeating in Java?

Tags: java, factorial

I'm trying to write a program to calculate factorial but I can't figure out why the Error message displays twice if I enter a letter instead of an integer.
I feel like the issue has to do with *Line 29* `c = sc.next().charAt(0);`, but am not sure how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

My program:

```java
public class Factorials {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        char c = 'Y';
        int num = 0;

        do
         {
            System.out.print("Enter a number to calculate its factorial: ");
            while (!sc.hasNextInt()) { 
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry - Enter only Integers! Try Again: ");
                sc.nextLine();
            }
            
            int result = 1;
            num = sc.nextInt();
            for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
                result = result * i;
            }
            System.out.println("The factorial of " + num + " is: " + result);
            
            System.out.println("Do you wish to continue? Y/N: ");
            
            c = sc.next().charAt(0);
        }while(c == 'y' || c == 'Y');
        sc.close();
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple fix: Change the `sc.nextLine();` in your code to a `sc.next()` and you should be good to go. This error occurs because `.nextLine()` considers the enter/return key as a separate character, while `.next()` doesn't. (The enter key when you press it after entering either 'y' or 'n': if you try it, the error message doesn't print twice if you enter a letter the first time you run the program).

Side note: You probably want it to be a `.print(/*invalid input sentence*/)` instead of a `.println()` to go along with how you take in your other number values.

Otherwise, you're good!

Comment: Thanks so much, it works perfectly now.  And thank you for the explanation so I understand the difference between .nextLine() and .next().

Answer (score 0):

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.
> A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches
> the delimiter pattern

As jdk doc shows, the 'sc.next' method will return when it reaches space, enter or return. So when you enter 'y' with enter, the enter character is still in buffer. You can assign sc.nextLine to a variable, like

```
String str = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(str);
```

You can see the enter character and your input character.

Both @TheSj and @Lahiru Danushka answer could solve this problem.

Comment: Yes, and also thank you for crediting us and not repeating the answer again!

Also, great explanation!

Answer (score -1):

add `sc.nextLine();` after `c = sc.next().charAt(0);`